# Formula para contar la cantidad de items en una lista de Python

Tags: python, lista

Mi problema es que estoy trabado y no logro la manera de determinar como calcular la cantidad de numeros repetidos

```
import random
lista=[]
for i in range(20):
    num=random.randint(0,100)
    lista.append(num)
print(lista)
```

Comment: Yo te comento como lo haría yo. Primero generaría esa lista aleatoria. A continuación 2 bucles anidados el primero que recorra desde 0 a 99 y el segundo desde 1 a 100, y que vaya comparando esos valores. Si lo encuentra está repetido y sumas 1 a una variable llamada repetidos. Si además es menor de 50 sumas 1 a la variable menor si es mayor, sumas 1 a la variable mayor,. Y además añades ese número a una lista. Luego muestras las variables y la nueva lista.

Answer (score 1):

empezaremos analizando bien el problema...

1. ***generar aleatoriamente 20 números pares entre 0 y 100***
   Para esto, debemos usar `randrange`, con el cual, luego del rango, pondremos el `step` = 2, ya que obtendremos numeros PARES de este modo.
2. ***Determinar cuántos vinieron repetidos***
   Para esto usaremos la respuesta de Nelson, la cual es perfecta.
3. ***¿Cuántos fueron por debajo del número 50?¿Cuantos por encima de 50?***
   Acá, usando un par de IF, podemos evaluar estas condicionales (no me queda claro si ambas son para la lista completa, o sin repeticiones, aclarame esa por favor.)
4. ***Mostrar todos los números ingresados, sin repeticiones.***
   Acá simplemente mostramos la lista generada por la respuesta de Nelson.

```
import random

lista=[]
con1 = 0
con2 = 0
con3 = 0

for i in range(20):
  num=random.randrange(0,100,2)
  lista.append(num)
  if num < 50:
    con1+=1
  if num > 50:
    con2+=1

b = set(lista)
resultado = len(lista) - len(b)

print(lista)
print(con1)
print(con2)
print(resultado)
```

Comment: Pero esta solución en realidad no aporta nada a la pregunta puesto que ya sabes de antemano el resultado de ese contador porque el el rango del bucle y aparte tampoco ves el incremento secuencial porque imprimes el resultado despues de terminar el bucle

Comment: Editó la respuesta mientras comentaba. De esta nueva forma no obtendrá 20 números pares sino 20 números aleatorios y dos contadores de cuáles están por encima o por debajo de 50 (sin tener en cuenta si se repiten más de dos veces)

Comment: formateada la respuesta más explicaciones

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes usar es set(), en la cual, le pasas una lista y te devuelve un conjunto de elementos únicos que posee la lista. Luego, usar el len() para saber la longitud final y compararlo con la longitud de la lista. La diferencia de longitudes es el resultado.

**Ejemplo**

```
a = [1,3,3,4,4,5]
conjunto = set(a)  #conjunto = {1, 3, 4, 5}
resultado = len(a) - len(conjunto)  #resultado = 2
```

El resultado final es que la lista contiene dos elementos repetidos

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar la clase *Counter* del módulo *collections*:

```
from collections import Counter

number_and_repetitions = Counter(lista)
print(number_and_repetitions)
```

Ahora *number_and_repetitions* será un diccionario donde cada *key* corresponde a cada uno de los números de *lista* y cada *value*, a la cantidad de veces que se repite en ella:

> lista = [71,
> 32,
> 68,
> 60,
> 83,
> 89,
> 27,
> 20,
> 61,
> 71,
> 61,
> 47,
> 15,
> 59,
> 62,
> 63,
> 26,
> 21,
> 66,
> 36]

> Counter({71: 2,
> 32: 1,
> 68: 1,
> 60: 1,
> 83: 1,
> 89: 1,
> 27: 1,
> 20: 1,
> 61: 2,
> 47: 1,
> 15: 1,
> 59: 1,
> 62: 1,
> 63: 1,
> 26: 1,
> 21: 1,
> 66: 1,
> 36: 1})

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, tenes q generar la lista aleatoria pero con numeros pares.
En el codigo que te dejo aca, te cuenta cuantas veces aparece cada numero en la lista, sabiendo eso ya es facil continuar el problema

```
import random
lista=[]
cont_repe = 0 
num = 0
for i in range(20):    
    lista.append(random.randrange(0, 100, 2))
print(lista)

for i in range(len(lista)):
    num = lista[i]
    print("num: " , num)
    for j in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[j] == num:
            cont_repe += 1
    print("cont_repe: " , cont_repe)
    cont_repe = 0
```